# Deploy spring boot microservices on AWS Appmesh with EC2

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-app-mesh

I am trying to deploy Spring Boot microservices using Docker using Appmesh and EC2. I have deployed two sample microservices (https://github.com/amitgct/appmesh-hello) namely: caller-service and called-service using docker on a single EC2 instance and configured appmesh accordingly by following guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/getting-started-ec2.html. Currently, my applications are running on ec2 but they cannot communicate with each other and getting error on calling called-service from caller-service i.e. Unknown host. Can anyone tell me how can I specify hostname and register service with that host on EC2 and App mesh. (Note: I don't want to use kubernetes, ECS, AWS cloud map, AWS Route53) . If can provide example also then very thankful to you. Please help.

Comment: did you got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.appmeshworkshop.com/servicediscovery/

here's a step by step process shown, and this is for http protocol...
but if you change the listeners section in virtual routes to tcp then it should work for TCP messages as well - for those systems which works on tcp protocol - example Akka Clusters